# TreeMap and LinkedHashMap classes

Tags: java, tree, treemap, linkedhashmap

I found a Java question J couldn't understand what should be answer

The `TreeMap` and `LinkedHashMap` classes:

1. enable iteration of a map's entries based on the insertion order  of elements only.
2. enable iteration of a map's entries based on natural ordering of keys only.
3. enable iteration of a map's entries in a deterministic order.
4. enable iteration of a map's entries based either natural ordering of keys OR natural ordering of values depending on the arguments sent to the contructor.

Comment: and the question is...how to pass my exam?

Comment: Lol @fantarama but indeed right !

Comment: Hint: Some of the statements apply to `TreeMap`, but not to `LinkedHashMap`. Other statements apply to `LinkedHashMap`, but not to `TreeMap`. Only one of the above four statements is correct about both `TreeMap` **and** `LinkedHashMap`. You need to find which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java:

1. **`TreeMap` is a `Map` that automatically sorts the `Map` entries according to its natural ordering using `Comparable<T>` interface**
2. **`LinkedHashMap` is Map that guarantees that the entries will be returned in the same order as they were added**